# How can I rearrange ($a$ * $b$)^$c$=$d$ to make $c$ the subject

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is it at all possible to rearrange this equation to make c the subject. My dad and I believe it is possible but I am unable to correctly rearrange for c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is done using your basic log rules.  The main rule to use is:
$$y=log_b(x)=>x=b^y$$

So in your case:

$$(a*b)^c=d$$
$$clog(ab)=log(d)$$
$$c=\frac{log(d)}{log(ab)}$$
$$(c=log_{ab}(d))$$

Comment: Awesome thank you i'd forgotten that logs could be used this way :)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: It is possible, but you'll need a logarithm to do it.

Logarithms are the inverses of exponents. If $\log_x(y)=z$, then $x^z = y$; that's the definition of a logarithm.

Can you find what x, y, and z should be in your equation?